# Scrapy returning empty list for xpath

Tags: javascript, python, html, web-scraping, scrapy

I am using Scrapy to get abstracts from openreview urls. For example, I want to get the abstract from http://openreview.net/forum?id=Bk0FWVcgx, and upon doing

`$ scrapy shell "http://openreview.net/forum?id=Bk0FWVcgx"
 $ response.xpath('//span[@class="note_content_value"]').extract()`

I get back `[]`. In addition, when I do `view(response)` I am lead to a blank site `file:///var/folders/1j/_gkykr316td7f26fv1775c3w0000gn/T/tmpBehKh8.html`.

Further, inspecting the openreview webpage shows me there are script elements, which I've never seen before. When I call

`response.xpath(//script).extract()` I get things back like `u'<script src="static/libs/search.js"></script>'` for example.

I've read a little bit about this having something to do with javascript, but I'm kind of a beginner with Scrapy and unsure how to bypass this and get what I want.

Comment: I used `DevTools` in Chrome/Firefox to see what urls are used by javascript/AJAX to get more data - and I found that page get content as JSON from http://openreview.net/notes?forum=Bk0FWVcgx&trash=true

Comment: That provides me with `{"errors":["User does not exist"]}`. Not sure what you mean.

Comment: maybe it needs some cookies or HTTP headers like `user-agent`. Sometimes helps if you first read oryginal page - and you get all cookies - and later read data.

Comment: I unfortunately don't know what you mean by `user-agent` and getting cookies. Kind of a newb. Not a lot of html scraping experience.

Comment: when browser sends `URL` to server then it pack it in `HTTP` which has some other information for server (similar people pack letter in envelope with addresses and stamp) `user-agent` is information about browser - name, version, OS system, etc. I checked and I get `error` if I don't use `cookies`

Comment: I see, somewhat. So how do I "use" `cookies`?

Comment: I get `cookies` from browser using `DevTool` because but normally server should assign different cookies to every user (and acceps them only for a short time). I see servers sends one `cookie` and page loads http://openreview.net/token to get second cookie.  When page has both cookies then it can load JSON data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that page uses JavaScript/AJAX to load all information from address
http://openreview.net/notes?forum=Bk0FWVcgx&trash=true

But it needs two cookies to get access to this information. First server sends cookie `GCLB`. Later page loads http://openreview.net/token and gets second cookie `openreview:sid`. After that page can load JSON data.

It is working example with `requests`

```
import requests

s = requests.Session()

# to get `GCLB` cookie
r = s.get('http://openreview.net/forum?id=Bk0FWVcgx')
print(r.cookies)

# to get `openreview:sid` cookie
r = s.get('http://openreview.net/token')
print(r.cookies)

# to get JSON data
r = s.get('http://openreview.net/notes?forum=Bk0FWVcgx&trash=true')
data = r.json()
print(data['notes'][0]['content']['title'])
```

---

Other solution: use `Selenium` or other tool to run JavaScript code and then you can get full HTML with all information. `Scrapy` probably can use `Seleniu` or `PhantomJS` to run JavaScript. But I newer try it with `Scrapy`.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: Given that I already have a large scrapy script which takes data from other sites, how could I incorporate this within scrapy? For instance, I have 

`s = requests.Session()`
`r1 = s.get(open_review_url)`
`r2 = s.get('http://openreview.net/token')`
`r3 = s.get(open_review_url + "&trash=true")`

and 

`request = scrapy.FormRequest(open_review_url, formdata = r2, callback = self.get_openreview_abstract)'
'yield request`

but I am getting errors.

Comment: No worries! I will figure it out. I had a silly typo. Thank you very much =]

Comment: first: first url and third url are more different than only `&trash=true`. `requests` use `Session` to keep all cookies. But scrapy doesn't has this cookies. `r2` is not form data - it `response` object - and it has headers, cookies, JSON data, and other elements.